# Export function variable / global variable?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development

```
modifier restriction(){msg.sender == 0x123456}

function myFunction() private restriction { int a = 1; int b = 2

int c = a+b; }
```

How do I access "c" from another function which is public view?
Basically I want to make "c" available for everyone, without them knowing "a" or "b". 
I can't find anything about global variables in solidity

Answer (score 2):

It's worth pointing out that `a` and `b` will be visible to any mildly interested adversary because they will be baked into the blockchain history - just in case confidentiality is important.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract State {

    uint public c;

    function updateC(uint a, uint b) public {

        c = a + b;

    }
}
```

You get a "free" getting function with `public`:

`function c() public view returns(uint) { return c; }`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was told that I can declare variables as public such as

```
int public c; 

function myFunction() private restriction { int a = 1; int b = 2

int c = a+b; }
```

I wasn't aware of this possibility!